# OpenSSL3.0 RSA Signature Verification in C

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I have an RSA keypair in the pem format on disk.
I am looking for a comprehensive example in C, on how I can load the private keyfile from disk, sign an example message and then verify the signature with the corresponding public key.

There are plenty of examples that utilize deprecated OpenSSL1.X functions (e.g. `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey`), but I can't seem to find a comprehensive example that uses OpenSSL3.0. Not even in the official documentation.

Can someone provide a short example, how I would load the keyfile from disk, and utilize it for sigining and verifying? I would show my own progress, but I don't even know where to get started.

Comment: The API is different, but not so much different that version 1.X examples are useless. You can get started with those. Note that "PEM format" is not enough detail to know what is inside. For example, the keypair could be in PKCS#1 format or PKCS#8 format and still be described as being in "PEM" format. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468 for more details.

Comment: The documentation of [`PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.3/man3/PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey.html) refers right at the beginning of the *Description* section to [`OSSL_DECODER_from_bio()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.3/man3/OSSL_DECODER_from_bio.html) as a possible alternative (that is not deprecated and) whose documentation also contains examples.